# Set max horizontal scroll of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have a jquery images scroller below that just scrolls horizontally left/right. The loop below could include an infinite number of images.

The problem I have is that while it scrolls left and right fine, once the images end you can just keep scrolling so essentially you're just scrolling over white space!

How can I set a max scroll so that when the images end it won't allow it to scroll anymore? Obviously the number of images is dynamic so it can have 1 or 100 images in there.

```
<div id="imgThumbs" class="scroller" style="position:relative;height:75px;width: 306px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">
    <a href="#" id="left-button" style="left:14px;top:25px;position:absolute;">
        <img src="left-button.png" width="20" height="20" />
    </a>  
    <a href="#" id="right-button" style="right:14px;top:25px;position:absolute;">
        <img src="right-button.png" width="20" height="20" />                               
    </a>
    <div id="contentScroller">                         
    <?php $counter = 1; while(the_repeater_field('images')): ?>                     
        <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="<?php echo the_sub_field('high_resolution_image'); ?>" style="text-decoration:none!IMPORTANT;color:white!IMPORTANT;" class="showImg">
            <img class="image-<?php echo $counter; ?>" src="<?php echo the_sub_field('image'); ?>" width="90" height="68" alt="<?php echo the_title(); ?> <?php echo $counter; ?>" />
        </a>
     <?php $counter++; endwhile; ?>
     </div>
</div>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#right-button').click(function() {
            $('#contentScroller').animate({
                marginLeft: "-=306px"
            }, "fast");
        });
        $('#left-button').click(function() {
            $('#contentScroller').animate({
                marginLeft: "+=306px"
            }, "fast");
        });                     
    });
</script>
```

### UPDATE

Here's a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jCskY/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the `marginLeft` with the *width* calculated by the sum of content `a`'s *widths*.

If the *margin* passes the *width*, it should hide the button. Otherwise, it should show.

Here is a snippet of how it would be implemented.

**[Also, see this fiddle, for live example!](http://jsfiddle.net/jCskY/14/)**

```
var updateRightLeftButtons = function() {
    if (306 > (parseInt($('#contentScroller').css('marginLeft')) * -1)) {
        $('#left-button').hide();
    } else {
        $('#left-button').show();
    }
    if ((($('#contentScroller a').width() * $('#contentScroller a').length) - 306) < (parseInt($('#contentScroller').css('marginLeft')) * -1)) {
        $('#right-button').hide();
    } else {
        $('#right-button').show();
    }
};
$('#right-button').click(function() {
    updateRightLeftButtons();
    if ($(this).is(':visible'))
    $('#contentScroller').animate({
        marginLeft: "-=306px"
    }, "fast", updateRightLeftButtons);
});
$('#left-button').click(function() {
    updateRightLeftButtons();
    if ($(this).is(':visible'))
    $('#contentScroller').animate({
        marginLeft: "+=306px"
    }, "fast", updateRightLeftButtons);
});
updateRightLeftButtons();​
```

Comment: Thanks. I had a go at that but it wouldn't allow for any scrolling. When you say "changes may be necessary" where do you mean?

Comment: To adjust when it would have to hide. Maybe it should be 0 instead of 306 in the updateRightLeftButtons function. If you made a fiddle would be great to help better.

Comment: Ok here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jCskY/ . (Hopefully I did the fiddle correct) It doesn't scroll at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$dirname = '_/img/album';
$pattern = "/(\.jpg$)/i"; // valid image extensions
if (is_dir($dirname)) {
    if ($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
        $count = 0;
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            // if this file is a valid image
            if (preg_match($pattern, $file)) {
                $count++;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
}
?>
```

then take the count multiplied by 20 and set the value to the width of div container